# Nodemon keep restarting my server when bundle.js changes

Tags: javascript, express, webpack, nodemon

How do I tell it to ignore this.

It does not need to re-start when client side files changes.

Is there a way to tell it to exclude certain files.

I can' imagine that the server is caching any of my client side files.  There would be no reason to do this.

Answer (score 0):

From `nodemon --help`:

```
-i, --ignore ............. ignore specific files or directories.
```

So use like:

```
nodemon . -i public/js/bundle.js
```

A better approach is to use NPM scripts, so in `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon . -i public/js/bundle.js",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

and then:

```
npm run dev
```

You can also use [nodemon's own config files.](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#config-files)

Comment: That also works, that becomes handy if you have a lot of config/parameters. NPM scripts are simpler and cleaner for smaller usage.